# The UIAlertView shows NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Does anybody by any chance created the weather app using this tutorial?

http://www.globalnerdy.com/2013/09/03/ios-fortnightly-tutorial-a-simple-weather-app-part-1/

So i've just created a weather app using this tutorial, if i type the weather in Toronto, UIAlertView will display everything null, but if i click the button one more time it will show the actual results.

Can someone say why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the `[theWeather getCurrent:]` calls `[operation start]` which is an asynchronous method. It will just send a request to get the weather information and return immediately, so the `UIAlertView` gets shown  while the data are still being downloaded/parsed.

A way to avoid this happening is to make the `getCurrent` method accept a successCallback which gets called after the data are parsed. This callback then creates and shows the `UIAlertView`.